# How to unmarshall object with jackson

Tags: java, jackson, unmarshalling

Given JSON as following

```
 [{"itemId":6,"itemTypeId":2,"expDate":"2021-04-17T22:00:00.000+00:00","creationDate":"2021-04-18T09:44:52.417+00:00","transactions":[{"transactionType":"USE","userId":0,"quantityBefore":6.0,"quantityAfter":4.0,"locIdBefore":2,"locIdAfter":2}]}]
```

I'am trying to unmarshall JSON to POJO defined as above, hovewer getting

```
UnsupportedOperationException
```

My idea was to use simple jackson mapping:

```
 public static ArrayList<HistoryItem> convert (String response){
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ArrayList<HistoryItem> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        itemList = (ArrayList<HistoryItem>)mapper.readValue(response, new TypeReference<List<HistoryItem>>(){});
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return itemList;
}
```

With simple objects having fields with simple object types such as String, Long, Integer etc. its working fine, however when I add ArrayList i got that error. Any ideas what is my problem?

My class HistoryItemDto:

```
public class HistoryItemDto {
private Long itemId;
private Long itemTypeId;
private Date expDate;
private Date creationDate;
private ArrayList<HistoryTransactionDto> transactions;}
```

My class HistoryTransactionDto:

```
public class HistoryTransactionDto {
private TransactionType transactionType;
private Long userId;
private float quantityBefore;
private float quantityAfter;
private Long locIdBefore;
private Long locIdAfter;}
```

They both include getters, setters, no parameters constructor and every parameter constuctor.

In advance.... Checked a lot websites as baeldung, jackson docs, posts from stackoverflow and found nothing answering mine cause.

Comment: Exactly what type of error are you getting?

Comment: @mnestorov `UnsupportedOperationException` as written in the post and it's only visible when tracing line 5 of `convert` method

Comment: My bad, completely missed that

Comment: In your `convert` method you use `HistoryItem`,
but later on you have class `HistoryItemDto`.
May be it is just a typo in your question. Or are these really two different classes?

Comment: If I rename HistoryItemDto to HistoryItem, it works perfectly. (JDK11)

Comment: @ThomasFritsch yes, please accept my excuses for my typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same issue and, in order to solve this problem, instead of using Lists (including ArrayList or any other type of iterator), use basic arrays:

```
public static ArrayList<HistoryItem> convert (String response) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ArrayList<HistoryItem> itemAsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        HistoryItem[] responseAsArray = mapper.readValue(response, HistoryItem[].class);
        
        Collections.addAll(itemAsArrayList, responseAsArray);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return itemAsArrayList;
}
```

Comment: Thank You @GuilgermeBarboza ! So answer is JACKSON have issues with marshalling objects containing ArrayList's of other object !